# React Native Axios -> wait for async response and navigate to new page if true

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am sending a POST with user credentials with axios in an React-Native App:

```
const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [pass, setPass] = useState('');

  async function onLoginPress() {
    await sendtoapi(user, pass);
    if(login==true){
      alert('Success, redirect to Details')
      navigation.navigate('Details');
    }
  ;}

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>App</Text>
            <TextInput placeholder="Username" placeholderColor="#c4c3cb" style={styles.loginFormTextInput} onChangeText={user => setUser(user)} />
            <TextInput placeholder="Password" placeholderColor="#c4c3cb" style={styles.loginFormTextInput} secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={pass => setPass(pass)}/>
            <Button
              buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
              onPress={() => onLoginPress()}
              title="Login"
            />
    </View>
  );
};
```

this is the axios function (sendtoapi):

```
async function sendtoapi(user, pass){
  var data = JSON.stringify({"user":user,"pass":pass});
  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/api/dev/',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data : data
  };
  
  axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    var res = response.data;
    if(res.login==true){
      login = true;
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Basically this code works, but I have to hit the "Login" Button twice, because it seems that the *var login* is not set to true after *await sendtoapi(user, pass);* so it is not waiting. What could couse this problem?

Comment: Don't use a global variable like that. Return true from sendToApi if login works, otherwise false. In onLoginPress() you do:
`const loggedIn = await sendtoapi(user, pass);`

Comment: That makes sense, but I have the same issue here. when I use the loggedIn after const *loggedIn = await sendtoapi(user, pass);* it's still undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a matter of double click in order to get the value, your `sendtoapi` function is not returning a Promise (that is related to the network request).

Refactor your code so it will return `axios`'s Promise, then the code that handles the global `login` param will run only after the server response.

```js
function sendtoapi(user, pass) {
  var data = JSON.stringify({ user: user, pass: pass });
  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/api/dev/',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: data,
  };

// --∨ this is required in order to the outer `await` will wait for the network request
  return axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      var res = response.data;
      return { isLoggedIn: res.login }; // it is better to return your "promised" value to the consumer
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

small refactor to the consumer code

```js
const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [pass, setPass] = useState('');

  async function onLoginPress() {
    const { isLoggedIn } = await sendtoapi(user, pass);
    // ---------^ the value which your promise returns
    if (isLoggedIn === true) {
      alert('Success, redirect to Details');
      navigation.navigate('Details');
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={styles.logoText}>App</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Username"
        placeholderColor="#c4c3cb"
        style={styles.loginFormTextInput}
        onChangeText={(user) => setUser(user)}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Password"
        placeholderColor="#c4c3cb"
        style={styles.loginFormTextInput}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={(pass) => setPass(pass)}
      />
      <Button buttonStyle={styles.loginButton} onPress={() => onLoginPress()} title="Login" />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Tip: don't use global / module vars for such tasks since it will be hard to expose it to the rest of the app.
I recommend you to store it on some react related storage (context / state).

Comment: This does not only answer my question and solve my problem, it does give me a lot more understanding of Await/Promise. Thank you very much @felixmosh!